# How To Detect Which Element Was Clicked, Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide

Hi friends i want the drop down menu just like facebook. when i click on the menu it want to be open and if  i again clicked it want to be close. 
And when it is open if i click on any other area then also it want to be close.... please help me.

**I used the jquery as below:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
 {
    $('.profile').on('click', function ()
    {
        $('.profile-mgnt').fadeToggle("slow").toggleClass('act_drop');
    });
    $('body').on('click', function (e)
    {
        if ($('.profile-mgnt').hasClass('act_drop'))
        {
            if (!$(e.target).parent().hasClass('profile-mgnt'))
            {
                $('.profile-mgnt').removeClass('act_drop');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get the ID of the control which is clicked then you can handle the classes.

Comment: @Shan why did you unaccept the answer?  Feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know what was clicked.  It could have been the drop down itself.  It could have been a link inside the drop down.  It could have been the textnode inside the link inside the drop down.  So using `parent` will only get you up ONE level from the target.  And actually, in this case `target` will be `body` since it propagated up to `body` so that won't help either.  [See this article about target vs currentTarget](http://blog.codeishard.net/2012/01/28/e-target-vs-e-currenttarget/).

So, what you really want is to say "If what I clicked doesn't have an ancestor with class profile-mgnt, then I want to close (remove the class)".

Something like this: `if(!$(e.currentTarget).closest('.profile-mgnt').length)`.  Closest goes up up the ancestor chain matching on the filter criteria, in this case *an ancestor with class .profile-mgnt*.  If it can't be found, then you didn't click **anywhere** inside the *profile-mgnt* scope, so `removeClass`.